# How to get the exacly source code of the actual page that I'm in?

Tags: javascript

To get the source code of a page we are in, Using JavaScript we can go with:

```
var pageSource = document.documentElement.outerHTML;
```

or

```
var pageSource = new XMLSerializer().serializeToString(document);
```

- The first one will not return the code before the `html` tag as `<!DOCTYPE html>`.
- Both of methods will remove some of line breaks in the begin and the end of the document.

So there are any alternative that will return the source code as the same as written without any need to a HTTP call?

Comment: The coder has a clearly stated, reasonable question, has clearly researched this already, and posted code that they have already tried. Why is this getting downvoted?

Comment: ^ That what is internet... They were 4 downvotes, I think you upvote the question... Thanks Chris ^^

Answer (score 1):

You can't. Once a web page has been loaded, the original source code is not kept around by the browser — `outerHTML` and `XMLSerializer` both attempt to reconstruct HTML (or XML) from the DOM tree. As you've discovered, this is an inexact process, due both to formatting quirks (e.g, line breaks), error recovery, elements that don't survive to the DOM at all (e.g, comments and NOSCRIPT tags) and DOM manipulations performed by Javascript running on the site.

Comment: Actually both get back the source code as it is, With comments and everything, My guess is the DOM tree content this data too in case of XMLSerializer, For outerHTML the part of innerHTML is as is, But the added syntax to get outerHTML it's look (badly) generated from the DOM tree.